# Code to set/unset checkbox buttons in Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying to use a button group (as per the instructions at  at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons) and then to parse their values into a shifted array:

**Code for the btn-group**

```
<div class="btn-group" id="weekdays" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="checkbox" >Mo
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="checkbox">Tu
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="checkbox">We
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Code for reading the values**

```
$("#weekdays ").change(function(event){

   var checkedDays = $("#weekdays :checkbox").map(function(){
        return $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
    }).get(); // <----

    var sun = checkedDays.pop();

    checkedDays.unshift(sun);

    console.log(checkedDays);
});
```

So far so good. (Even if I'm sure the code could be better written.)

However, my problem comes when I try to **set** the values of the checkboxes programatically, and get it reflected in the UI. I've sort of managed to change the values of the checkboxes using a number of methods `$(this).prop('checked', true)`, etc, which seems to update the backing values, but it does nothing to change the appearance of the buttons.

I've seen a number of solutions, but none that works with the Bootstrap 3.0 recommended way of setting up the checkbox `btn-group`. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use a DOM editor when clicking on the Bootstrap buttons, you'll see that a class `active` is added to the label (not the checkbox input) when the button is clicked.

To programmatically toggle the buttons, use the Bootstrap [`.button('toggle')`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-programmatic-api) method on the label:

```
$('#weekdays label').eq(n).button('toggle');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/4NVvj/

This will change both the appearance of the button and the `checked` property of the checkbox within.

Answer (score 6):

In a similar case what worked for me was this:

```
$('#checkBoxId').trigger("click");
```

Which does exactly what you want.

PS. Not sure if it is the best but it worked for me back then.

Comment: I cannot seem to get this to work, but thanks for your answer!